# UNIX expression to filter out PID from netstat output

Tags: unix, awk, grep, netstat, unix-socket

Below is Output of command:

```
netstat -plten|grep  45678
tcp        0      0 :::45678                    :::*                        LISTEN      0          129367622  109746/java
```

However, I want to get ‘109746’ as output.

I tried:

```
netstat -plten|grep  45678|awk ' {print$9}'
```

But this one gives `109746/java` as an output; is there any way, I can use `$9` to match with some regex such that I get desired output.

Comment: `netstat -plten | grep 45678 | awk '{print $9}' | sed -e 's/\/.*$//'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell awk to treat `/`, in addition to blank, as a field separator.  That way, `java` is considered a separate field and not included in field 9:

```
$ netstat -plten | awk -F'[ /]+' ' /45678/{print$9}'
109746
```

`-F'[ /]+'` tells awk to use a blank, a `/`, or any combination of those two as the field separator.

Also, the use of `grep 45678` in front of awk is not necessary.  In the above, the awk condition `/45678/` selects for lines containing `45678`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your response.

Comment: Produced blank output for me but here's what helped me: `netstat -ptan | awk -F'[ /]+' '{print$7}'`
Also, bonus: print full command line for found processes `netstat -ptan | grep 45678 | awk -F'[ /]+' '{print$7}' | sed -e 's/^/pidstat -l -p /g' | bash -s`